# Use google accounts to log into a sharepoint application

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, adfs

I have a SharePoint 2010 application that is extended for external users to use claims based authentication,  now the requirement is that the users should be able to use a trusted social log in accounts Google or MSN IDs to gain access to the site. This is possible using ADFS, but i have little idea on how i can add Google and others as trusted identity provider in ADFS.

Any help or reference to links are much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wictor Wilén recently wrote a post on using Azure Access Control Services to do this. The post is at http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-guide-to-Azure-Access-Controls-Services-authentication-with-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx

This is not using ADFS, but it shows access using both Google and Windows Live ID.

Comment: Thanks! I had explored on this too... But this method will incur the cost of subscription and also nominal fee to be paid for transactions. I would make this as my last option. I want to know if I can configure ADFS to do the same thing without ACS, also look at its pros and cons, doesnt matter if its time consuming!

Answer (score 1):

Danny Jessee has a blog post that shows how he integrated LinkedIn as an authentication source without using ACS. Reviewing how he did that might be useful for you. It builds on the Travis Neilsen blog article mentioned above.

http://www.dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/using-linkedin-as-an-identity-provider-for-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow steps in below post to get it done.

http://exploresharepointfeatures.blogspot.ae/2016/10/login-to-sharepoint-2013-using-google.html

This includes steps to

- Create google project through developer console.
- Set up Azure ACS to add google as identity provider using client key and client secret of project you created in google.
- Scripts to create new trusted identity provider in SharePoint.
- Testing

https://exploresharepointfeatures.com/2016/10/31/login-to-sharepoint-2013-onpremise-using-google-account/

Comment: This is a HowTo designed for SharePoint 2013. Your answer should clear out if this will also work with SharePoint 2010. It is also helpful to add some details to your answer as the Blog may become unavailable over time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to implement an OpenId Membership Provider for Claims.

Check out the following projects:

[OpenID Membership Provider](http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex to get you started.

[Shetab SharePoint Live Authentication](http://www.shetabtech.com/english/SharePointLiveAuth/default.aspx) for a commercial solution with more feature.

And this blog article:
http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/nielsen_travis/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=34

Just found (but looks partial) : 
[SharePoint 2010 Claims FBA Examples with OpenID](http://sp2010claimsfbaexs.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex too